# Images in CSS URLs not showing in GatsbyJS

Tags: webpack, gatsby

I have the following selector in `css/application.scss` :

```
#header-container {
  background: #333 url('../pages/images/home-head.jpg') center center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

When I preview the site with `gatsby develop` I see this in the web inspector:

```
#header-container {
  background: #333 url([object Object]) center center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Something is definitely not right with [object Object] but I'm having trouble tracking it down. Any hints on where I should look?

Comment: I have also tried simply `url('/images/home-head.jpg')` too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is Gatsby [doesn't (yet) include loaders for images](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/208) so you need to manually add that. See this issue for more background on this https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/287.

UPDATE:
This was fixed in the 0.12 release!
https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/releases/tag/v0.12.0